# All apps close when phone starts and won't stay open when manually activated

Tags: applications, samsung

Okay, so my dad is completely technology illiterate. He doesn't even understand that you don't click on internet popups. He's got a phone with Android 5.1.1 and he says he downloaded an app called Force Stop. Now when you turn on or unlock the phone, it goes through this big list of apps that its forcing to close including his calling app. You can't make calls cause it closes the app before you can dial the number. I can't figure it out guys. **What has he done to this phone and how can I fix it?**

Comment: why don't you uninstall this force close app and see what happens? you can always re-install it if required

Comment: I can't find it anywhere. its not in his apps list or his download history. Makes me think its either some form of malware or some feature that came with the phone.

Comment: Can you share some screen shots for better understanding.